How to upload pandas dataframe directly to SharePoint with Python
I am trying to upload a pandas dataframe to SharePoint directly from a python script (don't want to save anything locally)

I'm able to create SharePoint directories/folders from the script so I'm sure that my authentication process is working
The relative URL is correct as I used this to create directories/folders
df1 is the dataframe which has data in it for upload
My code runs with no errors however no file is uploaded to SharePoint

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated
My code is as follows ;
site_url = 'https://{Name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{SiteName}'
relative_url = f'Documents/Shared Documents/test'

context = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(sharepoint_clientID, sharepoint_clientSecret))


try:
    target_folder = context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_url)

    buffer = BytesIO() 
    df1.to_csv(buffer, index=False) 
    buffer.seek(0) 
    file_content = buffer.read() 
    file_name = 'test.csv'
    target_folder.upload_file(file_name, file_content).execute_query()

except Exception as e:
        print('Problem uploading to Sharepoint: ', e)


The reason this code was failing was because the code was looking for a file called test.csv in the SharePoint Directory to overwrite. I had nothing in the target folder and so the code could not find the file to overwrite
